# Play animation again when reverse scrolling

Tags: javascript, tween, gsap, scrollmagic

I have this:

```
var controller = new ScrollMagic.Controller
var myTween = TweenMax.from('section',1,{opacity:0});

var myScene = new ScrollMagic.Scene({
    triggerHook= '.5',
    duration:'100%',
    reverse:false

})
 .setTween(myTween)
 .addTo(controller)
```

So this plays when the scrollDirection is 'FORWARD' and starts in the middle of the section, right? But how do I implement the same Tween when the user is scrolling up and reaching the bottom of the same "section" element?

Note that I don't want to play the animation in reverse, I want it to be played from the beginning (opacity:0)

Is there a simple way of doing this?

Comment: What currently happens when you scroll up from the bottom?

Comment: In this case nothing happens since reverse property is set to false. The Scene stays in its final state (opacity:1)